# Proof of $\sqrt{n^2-4}, n\ge 3$ being irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, radicals, rationality-testing

Is the proof of $n\ge 3$, $\sqrt{n^2-4} \notin \mathbb{Q} \ \text{correct}$?

$\sqrt{n^2-4} \in \mathbb{Q}
\\
\sqrt{n^2-4} = \frac{p}{q}
\\
(\sqrt{n^2-4})^2 =  \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2  
\\
q^2\left( n^2-4\right)=p^2
\\
\text{p is divisible by} \left (n^2-4 \right)
\Rightarrow p=k\left (n^2-4 \right)
\\
q^2 \left (n^2-4 \right)=k^2 \left(n^2-4 \right)^2
\\
q^2=k^2 \left (n^2-4 \right )\Rightarrow 
\text{it follows that q is also divisible by} \left (n^2-4 \right)
\\
\text{Therefore p and q are not co-prime therefore} \Rightarrow  \sqrt{n^2-4} \notin \mathbb{Q} \ 
\square
$

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Do you understand where the condition $n \geq 3$ comes in?

Comment: $p$ is divisible by $n^2-4$ is a non sequitur (at least a not-so-easily sequitur). To test it: Your proof as it stands suggests that it might work just as well if one replaces $4$ with $5$, thus proving that for all $n\ge 3$ we have $\sqrt{n^2-5}\notin \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks, the condition is provided in the question i have answered.

Comment: What should i write then ?

Comment: I would prove this in two parts: 1. Show that $n^2-4$ can't be a perfect square if $n \ge 3$ (this part _fails_ for $\sqrt{n^2-5}$); 2. show that if an integer $m$ is not a perfect square, then $\sqrt m$ is irrational.

Comment: You have that $p^2$ is divisible by $n^2-4$, which does not imply that $p$ is divisible by $n^2-4$: think to $n=4$ and $p=6$: it's true that $p^2=36$ is divisible by $n^2-4=12$, but $6$ is not divisible by $12$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not give sufficient reason why $p$ is divisible by $n^2-4$ should hold.
Consider this modified "proof" of $n\ge 3 \implies
\sqrt{n^2-5} \notin \mathbb{Q}$:

$$
\sqrt{n^2-5} \in \mathbb{Q}
\\
\sqrt{n^2-5} = \frac{p}{q}
\\
(\sqrt{n^2-5})^2 =  \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2  
\\
q^2\left( n^2-5\right)=p^2
\\
\text{p is divisible by} \left (n^2-5 \right)
\Rightarrow p=k\left (n^2-5 \right)
\\
q^2 \left (n^2-5 \right)=k^2 \left(n^2-5 \right)^2
\\
q^2=k^2 \left (n^2-5 \right )\Rightarrow 
\text{it follows that q is also divisible by} \left (n^2-5 \right)
\\
\text{Therefore p and q are not co-prime therefore} \Rightarrow  \sqrt{n^2-5} \notin \mathbb{Q} \ \square$$

This proof *must* be wrong because $n=3$ leads to $\sqrt{n^2-4}=2\in\mathbb Q$.

---

How can the proof be repaired? 
First show that $n^2-4$ is not a perfect square (which would be a desaster for the claim, as $n^2-4=m^2$ implies $\sqrt{n^2-4}=m\in\mathbb Q$).
So assume $n^2-4=m^2$ with $0\le m<n$. Then $4=n^2-m^2=(n+m)(n-m)$. Compare this with the few possible factorizatons of $4$: The possibility  $n+m=4$, $n-m=1$ leads to $n=\frac 52\notin\mathbb N$; the posssibility $n+m=n-m=2$ leads to $n=2$, which fails the important given condition $n\ge 3$.
So we conclude that $n^2-4$ is not a perfect square. Can you show (or do you already know) the important theorem:

> If the positive integer $N$ is not a perfect square, then $\sqrt N\notin\mathbb Q$.

*Hint:* One can write $N=m^2k$ where $k$ is a product of one or more distic primes. Use  *one* of these primes to show that $\sqrt k$ is irrational.

Comment: I see the problem but cant find sufficient reason.

Comment: As the failing 5 variant shows, sufficient reason *cannot* be given.

Answer (score 0):

The fault is when you deduce that $p$ is divisible by $n^2-4$ from the fact that
$$
q^2(n^2-4)=p^2
$$
which only implies that $p^2$ is divisible by $n^2-4$.

This would be true if $n^2-4$ is prime, but it isn't in general. For instance, if $n=4$ and $p=6$, $p^2=36$ is divisible by $n^2-4=12$, but $6$ is not divisible by $12$.